# Convert Java Object into JSON Object

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using Airbyte to sync MongoDB data into Snowflake. For some reason, our JSON lists are synched as what appear to be Java Objects.

I am trying to get the data into a JSON format, so I can work with the properties.

Example of Java object row in our cost column:

`"[Document{{currency=USD, value=815.00}}, Document{{currency=EUR, value=671.00}}, Document{{currency=GBP, value=579.00}}, Document{{currency=DKK, value=4992.00}}, Document{{currency=SEK, value=6760.00}}]"`

I want to convert the row into the following format

```
[{
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": 815.00
}, {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "value": 671.00
}, {
    "currency": "GBP",
    "value": 579.00
}, {
    "currency": "DKK",
    "value": 4992.00
}, {
    "currency": "SEK",
    "value": 6760.00
}]
```

How can I accomplish that in Snowflake?

Comment: Can you share the code that produces this output? I'm looking for a suitable parser for this, but I can't match it with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex but it's not the most elegant way:

```
set term='[Document{{currency=USD, value=815.00}}, Document{{currency=EUR, value=671.00}}, Document{{currency=GBP, value=579.00}}, Document{{currency=DKK, value=4992.00}}, Document{{currency=SEK, value=6760.00}}]';
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace($term, 'Document',''), '}}', '}'), '{{', '{');
```

I get:

```
[{currency=USD, value=815.00}, {currency=EUR, value=671.00}, {currency=GBP, value=579.00}, {currency=DKK, value=4992.00}, {currency=SEK, value=6760.00}]
```

This can be further extended to replace **currency** with **"currency"**.